# How to generate video from photos with animation on server?

Tags: animation, video, image-processing, ffmpeg, multimedia

Good day!

I create programm for server, which should generate a video clip of the photos. The user sends photos to the server and the server generates a video with animation and sound track from this photos. I use ffmpeg for creation video, but how to create animation?. I need different (difficult) animation: transitions (fade in, fade out, scroll), zooming, animations numbers etc.

This [example](http://www.instagram.com/p/igEizakDw9/) explains what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want a clone of animoto or stupeflix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should certainly check the [MLT framework](http://www.mltframework.org). It is used by many video editors, and supports different transitions in a quite easy form.

Check also Openshot which is video editing software written in Python. It also uses MLT framework, and due to being written in Python the code is rather easy to read.